# Count number of days between two dates

Tags: ruby, activesupport

How do I count the number of days between these two dates?

```
start_date = Date.parse "2012-03-02 14:46:21 +0100"
end_date =  Date.parse "2012-04-02 14:46:21 +0200"
```

Answer (score 255, accepted):

With the Date (and DateTime) classes you can do `(end_date - start_date).to_i` to get the number of days difference.

Comment: yeah but user has strings and you can't do this with strings.  You need them as dates.  See my answer for adding in to_date from core extensions.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant You are making an unwarranted assumption. The user does not specify if they are strings or not. In fact since they are using Rails it's most likely the dates are coming from ActiveRecord which will automatically cast them to date objects. The given text is identical to Date object representation as well, making it highly likely it's come from a native source.

Comment: Correct I am assuming the user tried a - b and it didn't work so they ended up posting on SO.  I guess only andkjaer can tell us the real deal :)

Comment: That gives me the difference in seconds NOT in days with rails v3/4

Comment: As far as I can tell the behaviour remains the same in all recent versions of Ruby and ActiveSupport, include 2.0 and 4.1.0 respectively. `Time` objects do return seconds though.

Comment: to expand on @2called-chaos answer, to get days you would need (end_date - start_date)/1.day, which would give you a float.  If you wanted to have full days only you might use ((end_date - start_date)/1.day).ceil

Comment: @David Except that the comment by @2called-chaos is mistakenly referring to `Time` objects, not `Date` objects. Perhaps you could update the naming in your comment to reflect that they are not dates?

Comment: @AndrewFrance - adding to Andrews comment, it seems some functions convert a Date object to a Time object.    If you do (Date.today.advance(weeks: 1) - Date.today).to_i it will be in days, but if you add a .beginning_of_day after both the Date.todays,  it will come out in seconds because it was converted to time

Comment: `(end_date - start_date).to_i / 1.day`

Answer (score 143):

Assuming that `end_date` and `start_date` are both of class `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` in Rails, then you can use:

```
(end_date.to_date - start_date.to_date).to_i
```

Comment: If it has to do with table fields, this answer is the way to go; instead of the most rated one right here.

Comment: Doesn't work for `(Time.zone.now.to_date - 23.hours.ago.to_date).to_i`, it gives 1 and should be 0

Comment: @YuriGhensev, it depends on when you run your example code, for example right now `Time.zone.now.to_date` returns "Wed, 15 Nov 2017", while `23.hours.ago.to_date` returns "Tue, 14 Nov 2017".  The difference in number of days is and should be 1 unless you ran your code in the hour before midnight.

Answer (score 41):

Rails has some built in [helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) that might solve this for you. One thing to keep in mind is that this is part of the Actionview Helpers, so they wont be available directly from the console.

Try this

```
<% start_time =  "2012-03-02 14:46:21 +0100" %>
<% end_time   =  "2012-04-02 14:46:21 +0200" %>
<%= distance_of_time_in_words(start_time, end_time)  %>

 "about 1 month"
```

Comment: @MaayanNaveh it should not be when you need the actual number for calculations.

Comment: This question is one of those cases where the the question itself is better off asked differently. If you follow the other answers here you'll run into cases where sometimes you want weeks or years shown instead of days. This really should be accepted as the "right" Rails answer.

Answer (score 36):

to get the number of days in a time range (just a count of all days)

```
(start_date..end_date).count
(start_date..end_date).to_a.size
#=> 32
```

to get the number of days between 2 dates

```
(start_date...end_date).count
(start_date...end_date).to_a.size
#=> 31
```

Comment: Thanks for this @a14m ! Gave me a way to do inclusive and exclusive date captures :)

Answer (score 35):

I kept getting results in seconds, so this worked for me:

```
(Time.now - self.created_at) / 86400
```

Comment: @Epigene `1.day` is not `ruby` as OP requested (in tags). It's `Rails` or more specific `active support` though `created_at` is basically a `Model` method in `Rails` so..

Answer (score 20):

None of the previous answers (to this date) gives the correct difference in days between two dates.

The one that comes closest is by [thatdankent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27091635/268016). A full answer would convert `to_i` and then divide:

```
(Time.now.to_i - 23.hours.ago.to_i) / 86400
>> 0

(Time.now.to_i - 25.hours.ago.to_i) / 86400
>> 1

(Time.now.to_i - 1.day.ago.to_i) / 86400
>> 1
```

In the question's specific example, one should not parse to `Date` if the time passed is relevant. Use `Time.parse` instead.

Comment: This may not work as expected when the times cross a DST transition moving forward.  In this case, the DST transitional day length is legitimately less than 24 hours, but because of the integer arithmetic that day will not be reflected at all.

Answer (score 9):

Very late, but it may help others:

```
end_date.mjd - start_date.mjd
```

https://apidock.com/ruby/Date/mjd

Hint: This works only for Date objects, not Time objects.

Answer (score 6):

To have the number of whole days between two dates (`DateTime` objects):

```
((end_at - start_at).to_f / 1.day).floor
```

Comment: Same DST issue as the answer that Yuri gave.  Arithmetic with time is never as straightforward as you'd expect :)

Answer (score 5):

The best solution currently that I've seen work consistently well is using the following pattern:

```
(end_date.beginning_of_day - Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day).seconds.in_days
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of days difference by two dates:

```
(start.to_date...end.to_date).count - 1
or 
(end.to_date - start.to_date).to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(end_date - start_date)/1000/60/60/24
```

any one have best practice please comment below

Answer (score 0):

```rb
start_date = 2.years.ago
end_date = 6.months.ago
diff = end_date - start_date

duration = ActiveSupport::Duration.build(diff)
=> 1 year, 6 months, 1 day, 3 hours, 16 minutes, and 12.64903700351715 seconds
duration.parts
=> {:years=>1, :months=>6, :days=>1, :hours=>3, :minutes=>16, :seconds=>12.64903700351715}
duration.in_days
=> 549.0
```

Documentation: [ActiveSupport::Duration](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html)

Answer (score -9):

```
def business_days_between(date1, date2)
  business_days = 0
  date = date2
  while date > date1
   business_days = business_days + 1 unless date.saturday? or date.sunday?
   date = date - 1.day
  end
  business_days
end
```

Comment: much easier to subtract the date objects.

Comment: The OP never asked about adjusting for business days. This is really convoluted anyway.