# Rails age of an article in days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to get the age of the article in days. For example, the article was written on `Tue, 01 Apr 2014 18:31:07 EDT -04:00` and now I need the days from that date to now printed as an integer. How can I do so?

Comment: This question is similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572860/rails-count-number-of-days-between-two-dates) which has several answers and a lengthy discussion.

Answer (score 0):

With the Date class you can do

```
(Date.today - @article.created_at.to_date).to_i
```

to get the number of days between the two dates.

Comment: I removed the to_date and added `60 / 60 / 24` at the end, which did the trick:
`(Time.now - @article.created_at) / 60 / 60 / 24`

Comment: Yes you could do that, but this looks better to me I guess.

Comment: Depending on how old your version of ruby is, this can cause a TypeError (as it tries to subtract a Time from a Date).

Comment: Edited to use `to_date`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:

```
gem install time_diff
```

install the gem.

```
require 'time_diff'

time_diff_components = Time.diff(start_date_time, end_date_time)

time_diff_components[:year], time_diff_components[:month], time_diff_components[:week]
```

This will give more option.

More detail [click](https://github.com/abhidsm/time_diff)

Comment: is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the cleverest way, but it's probably the simplest: use a "magic number": **86400**, which is the number of seconds in a day.  (you probably already know there are 3600 seconds in an hour, mentally file this number alongside that)

Differences between Time/DateTime objects will be in seconds (as a float).  If you divide this  by 86400 you get the difference in days, as a float.  You can then call to_i on this to get it as an integer if you want.

eg

```
((Time.now - @article.created_at)/86400).to_i
```

It's probably worth saving this as a constant, egs SECONDS_IN_A_DAY or something, to avoid mistyping.