# How to calculate days passed since date

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a record that has a field `created_at` with the following format: `created_at: Tue, 26 Jan 2016 23:31:27 UTC +00:00`.

I can compare it against specific days doing something like: `created_at >= 5.days.ago`.

Is there a simple way to calculate how many days have passed since a date object like `created_at` without iterating over `n.days.ago`?

Comment: Does `created_at` return a Date Object?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". As is it looks like you want us to write code for you, which is not what Stack Overflow is for. Please include the minimal example of the code you've written and we'll help you fix it. If you haven't written code, why not? Where have you searched and what about those references didn't help you? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 and http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints are also good reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "[Count number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572860/rails-count-number-of-days-between-two-dates)" and assuming that `created_at` returns a `Date` object, it seems like you can use:

```
(Time.current.to_date - Record.created_at).to_i
```

to get the difference in days

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.today.downto(Record.created_at).count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(Time.current.to_date - Record.created_at.to_date).to_i
```

As the returned value from Record.created_at is a string, you need to convert it to date as shown above